# I can't figure out what is wrong with this code

Tags: html, css

This code gives me: [image of broken layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrX7F.jpg)
I just want the `p` tag class `.mailtext` to be inside the footer and not outside as it does.

I don't know if this counts as you doing my homework but this is driving me crazy the last two days. The first `p` tag (the copyright text) works perfectly, but the second one is not. I have tried a lot of different solutions. I have come up with solutions such as changing the `overflow`, `z-index`, making `div` container bigger, but nothing worked. I am a student and not experienced. Any ideas?

```css
.footer {
  /* more info footer  */
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.rights {
  /* copyright paragraph */
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 170px;
}
.mail {
  /* mail icon properties */
  position: relative;
  bottom: 140px;
  left: 377px;
}
.mailtext {
  /* my email text properties */
  position: relative;
  color: red;
}
.feedback {
  /* feedback icon properties */
  position: relative;
  bottom: 190px;
  left: 430px;
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="moreinfo">
    <!-- more info footer -->
    <p class="rights">&#169;2017 annu.com. All rights reserved.</p>
    <!--   copyright symbol  -->
    <a target="_blank" href="">
      <img class="feedback" src="">
    </a>
    <!--  feedback logo -->
    <img class="mail" src="">
    <!-- mail logo -->
    <p class="mailtext">aaaaaa@gmail.com</p>
  </div>
</footer>
<!-- /Footer -->
```

Comment: what is the expected result you're looking to get? you didn't specify what the issue is exactly

Comment: What's supposed that you want to get? A simple drawing image may be enough and a screen shot.

Comment: @AngeloNuho the problem is with the `height: 200px;` it's too low for one thing for the `.footer` class. That's why you're not seeing it. Best to use a percentage rather than a fixed height or none at all. `height: auto;` will also work, and `text-align: center;` for the `.mailtext` class so that it too is center-aligned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.rights` has a large `margin-top` on it. This makes it start near the bottom of the footer.

The paragraph after it, appears after it, below the footer (and off the screen).

You need to leave enough space (whether by increasing the height of the footer, using a minimum instead of fixed height, using a smaller margin on the paragraph, or some other means) for your content to appear in.

Comment: well, that also would do it. I thought [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41509641/i-cant-figure-out-what-is-wrong-with-this-code#comment70225437_41509641) would have solved this (also), but he didn't respond to it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- well this is more eye catching it was the first thing i saw when checked my question :/

Comment: @AngeloNuho I believe Quentin's solution requires less code than my comment/answer. If you feel that it solved the question, it should be accepted even though it is a community wiki.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I believe this solves my problem better thanks for your time.